# Running service at fixed time

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, android-alarms

I am following [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

But I don't want to restart the phone each time to update the **REPEAT_TIME**. And I have something weird on manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and

```
<receiver android:name="MyScheduleReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I don't want anything related to BOOT on my app. What can I do?
**EDIT:**
And when I completely uninstall the app and try to run it. The service won't start. I need to restart the phone and run it again. Why so? **I don't want to restart the phone**

Comment: **"I don't want to restart the app"** : If you uninstall and reinstall the app then you MUST restart it. As of Android v3.1 an app MUST be started manually by a user after installation. This is to make sure users have 'approved' the app in order to prevent malware.

Comment: sorry that was mistake in typing. I have changed it to PHONE :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyScheduleReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

to your manifest will ensure that the `MyScheduleReceiver` is called when the android device reboots.

As to why you might need this :

If you set up Alarms using the `AlarmManager` to schedule something, android will kill your alarm when your phone turns off, so you'll need to setup the alarm again when your phone restarts. and you can then do this in your `MyScheduleReceiver`.

Comment: In that case just go ahead and setup the alarms. they'll execute automatically.

Comment: I am referring this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324693/my-alarmmanager-for-service-update-doesnt-work But whose OnCreate are you talking?

Comment: The MainActivity of your application. You can setup the alarms there.

Comment: HUH??? I am trying to integrate the reboot thing as well.. But it's either not starting or continuing even if i called stopService(...)

Comment: Well, if you want to do this on reboot as well, setup alarms inside the onReceive() method of the broadcast receiver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56759/discussion-between-nabin-and-shivam-verma).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear and the tutorial in the link you posted is actually very broad so it's unclear what you are trying to do.

From your question I can only assume you are trying to use `AlarmManager` to create an alarm to start a `Service` periodically.

In that case you should be aware that alarms are deleted when a device is powered off / rebooted. That means it is normal to use a `BroadcastReceiver` to recreate any alarms when the device reboots.

If a device isn't powered off a repeating alarm will remain without you having to do anything.

Comment: If there is AlarmManager, there should be a reboot? and if so, what should I do to call the service in some specific interval?

Comment: @Nabin : No. You simply create the alarm the first time your app starts. After that though, if the device is rebooted and you want the alarm to be automatically recreated then the `BroadcastReceiver` which receives `BOOT_COMPLETED` can do it for you.

Comment: No! Your alarms will execute fine as long as the phone isnt turned off. But just in case the user turns off the phone, the alarms that were supposed to execute at some time in the future, never will.